# FLA files created on Flash CS4 are publishing bigger SWF when imported to CS5

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, flash-cs5, fla

I have a big project created on Flash CS4, and now we're migrating to CS5.
The problem is that some SWF files are getting a lot bigger than before, like **3.147 KB** file, going to **3.901 KB**, making this migration inacceptable.

Someone can give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish from flash, check the option to publish a size report under publish settings on Flash tab.
You will be able to compare the export size of each item. My guess it is the difference in the font export options between CS4 and CS5.[image]

Comment: Yes, I adjusted all my font imports, unchecking the "All" glyphs importing which came in some fonts, but I still have half of the exceeding size to search for. Thanks for the **Generate size report** tip.